# import csv into MySQL ( UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte )

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem when importing csv.

my code:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
from datetime import datetime
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.20", user="xxx", password="xxxx", database="admin_mt")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE wp_dbo_iclock_transaction2")

csv_data = csv.reader(open('dbo_iclock_transaction.csv'))
header = next(csv_data)


print('Importing the CSV Files')
for row in csv_data:
  
    punch_time = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO wp_dbo_iclock_transaction2
                                  (id, emp_code, punch_time)
                                       VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",
                                       (row[0], row[1], punch_time))

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print('Done')
```

The error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Server Backup\time_import\import.py", line 13, in <module>
    header = next(csv_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp874.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 310: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm not sure what caused the problem. Or maybe it's because the csv file is encoding utf8 !

Comment: You need to specify the correct `encoding` option when you open the file.

Comment: csv_data = csv.reader(open('dbo_iclock_transaction.csv', encoding='utf-8'))  not working

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding. Your file is apparently using a different encoding.